# Update the text color in CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Problem is that i can't update a **box** using Javascript.
I want to change the text color of **box** from *blue* to **gree**

Style :

```
<style type="text/css">
      #grid {
        background-color: #ccc0b3;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .box {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 80px;
      }
    </style>
```

JavaScript : creating the class named **box**

```
function makeNew(row, col) {
      var number = Math.random() < 0.9 ? 2 : 4;
      var color = pikColor(number);
      var textcolor = textColor(number);

      return grid[row][col] = $('<div>')
        .css({
          background: color,
          color: "blue",
          top  : row * 100 + 'px',
          left : col * 100 + 'px'
        })
        .text(number)
        .addClass('box')
        .appendTo($('#grid'));
    }
```

updating the text color to gree :

```
function merge(row1, col1, row2, col2) {
      if (merging[row2][col2]) {
        return false;
      }

      grid[row2][col2].remove();
      grid[row2][col2] = grid[row1][col1];
      grid[row1][col1] = null;
      var number = grid[row2][col2].text() * 2 ;
      var color = pikColor(number);
      var textcolor = textColor(number);
      alert(number);
      alert(textcolor);
      merging[row2][col2] = true;

      grid[row2][col2]
        .css({
          background: color,
          color: textColor,
          top  : row2 * 100 + 'px',
          left : col2 * 100 + 'px'
        })
        .text(number);

      return true;
    }
```

here is the **textColor** function

```
function textColor(number){
    var textColor ;
     if(number<=4){
     textColor="#776E65";
     }
     else{
     textColor="#F9F6F2";
     }
     return textColor;
    }
```

Comment: Where's your textColor() function?

Comment: Are the rest of the CSS styles taking place from the merge function? Is the color the only thing not working?

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Isn't the `grid[row2][col2].remove();` removing the entire div?

Comment: I tried the cange the **background** and it works. but the text **color** don't change.
i added the *textcolor()* , it works @aldux

Comment: @mhu no it remove just the 'grid[row2][col2].remove();' to get a new grid

Comment: I don't understand if i change `color="#F9F6F2"` it works but `color=textcolor` don't. it tested the function and it gives the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the **textColor** to **textcolor**

```
color: textColor,
```

to

```
color: textcolor,
```